# Multiple variable plot, line style and thickness, black and white

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hey there I'm new to R and have a very small question

I have the following dataset:

```
head(risk_free_rate_comparison)

   Dates `       Swap rate` `Sovereign bond yield rate` `Swap rate - Sovereign bond yield rate`
  <dttm>         <dbl>       <dbl>                       <dbl>
1 2007-01-02     408.9       380.9568                    27.9432
2 2007-01-03     410.3       380.4535                    29.8465
3 2007-01-04     409.2       381.3993                    27.8007
4 2007-01-05     414.3       385.0663                    29.2337
5 2007-01-08     413.1       384.2545                    28.8455
6 2007-01-09     415.5       384.9770                    30.5230
```

,with the following plot:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Dates, value, color = variable, linetype = variable)) +
+     geom_line() +
+     labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL) +
+     theme_classic() +
+     theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
+     ylab("Rates in bp")
+ theme(
+ legend.position = "bottom",
+ legend.direction = "vertical",
+ legend.box.margin = margin(t = 20),
+ axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)),
+ axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20))
+ )
```

[image: riskfreeratescomparison]

Now I would like to change the line colours of the three variables to black and white style. And maybe varying line thicknesses or something in that way in order to be able to distinguish the lines.

Comment: You can manually change the line colour, line width and linetype using `scale_colour_manual()`, `scale_linetype_manual()`, `scale_size_manual()`. You don't provide a reproducible example, so have a look at e.g. `?scale_colour_manual` for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rbonac, see if this helps you out, and feel free to experiment by commenting out different layers or using scale_line_manual() to set your colors manually.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, labels = c("4", "6", "8"))) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl, linetype = cyl)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Rates in bp") + 
  scale_linetype_discrete() + 
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.box.margin = margin(t = 30),
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each variable to a line width using size aesthetic, and manually change line color and size to desired values using `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_size_manual`

```
ggplot(d, aes(Dates, value, color = variable)) + 
   geom_line(aes(linetype = variable, size=variable)) + 
   labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL, size = NULL) + 
   theme_classic() + 
   theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
   ylab("Rates in bp") +
   scale_colour_manual(values=c("gray50", "gray25", "gray0")) + 
   scale_size_manual(values=c(1, 1.5, 2)) + 
  theme(
   legend.position = "bottom",
   legend.direction = "vertical",
   legend.box.margin = margin(t = 20),
   axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)),
   axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 20))
   )
```